# Don't render form field, symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I don't want some fields to show. I tried it like this

```
{{form_start(form)}}
{{form_widget(form)}}
{% do form.password.setRendered %}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

But It doesn't work.

This is my form class. I don't want `password` field showing.

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('username')
                ->add('email')
                ->add('password')
                ->add('type', ChoiceType::class, array(
                    'choices' => array(
                        'User' => 'ROLE_USER',
                        'Admin' => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
                        ),
                    ))
                ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
                ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the order of the lines and first tell that `password` field is rendered, before rendering the form itself:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}

{% do form.password.setRendered %}
{{ form_widget(form) }}

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Answer (score -1):

From the `Form/UserType.php` class, remove this line:

```
->add('password')
```

And it won't be rendered anymore.